# Python Black Code Formatter - Is there any way to apply automatic black formatting before commiting project to Github

Tags: python, github, code-formatting, automated-refactoring, black-code-formatter

Recently I started to use [Black](https://github.com/psf/black#:%7E:text=Black%20can%20be%20installed%20by,pip%20install%20black%5Bjupyter%5D%20.) code formatter for my projects and sometimes it can be hard to track did I formatted all my changed files or not.
Let's assume that my project contains 20 different scripts (.py files) and I made changes on last 5 of them what I do normally before commit.

First option

```
black /project_directory
```

Second option

```
black script1.py

black script2.py
```

and etc.

Is there a way to automate this process before git commit or not ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use a pre-commit hook. If you're using Linux or macOS, or Windows with Git Bash, put the following in a file named `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Paths are relative to the root of the git repository
black .
black script1.py
black script2.py
```

Use `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit` to make this runnable. Then, every time you do a `commit`, the hook will run first and format all your code. You can read more about hooks on the [Git Hooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).